# Getting 155 error notification (requests /sec ) reached (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am developing an app with unity using parse. Now, I know I can increase the req/s limit but I wouldn't like to make it in advance. The question is : how can I get notified (email maybe) if the limit is reached at some point.

I first tried to get the 155 code and call a url from unity that than notifies my via script. Later I found out in Unity can only get error code -1 (Other cause); So i am looking for another solution, cloud code, parse sends me email.

I know I can access the data and see if the limit was reached in the dashboard but I cannot be watching that 24h a day (maybe there is any way to query that data?)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

not sure but you can use robot like script may be written in such a way which will keep hitting your dashboard and a check a specific parameter in the dashboard. Once the parameter excides some value it will trigger an automated email to you.

This is how we check the health of our application in terms of App up\App down\App usages. 
Regards
Pawan